# Where Do I place My Assignment?

Tags: python, variables, integer, variable-assignment, currency

I have created a program where you can "hack" fake bank accounts for money based on what the password for the account is. I assigned `money` as 0 (since the game is the type of game that restarts each time you open it), and `lives` as 100 since you have 100 lives to get as much money as you can. Here's the code:

```
#PASSWORD GUESSING MONEY GAME
#
#
#
#
import random
import time

print('Hello, please enter a name for your bank account.')
bank_acc = input()
print('Welcome to your bank account: ' + bank_acc)
print("$$$: 0")
print('Just press ENTER when ready.')
print('At the press of a button, you will have access to hundreds of millions of bank accounts.')
print('But do not be so quick, you will be required to hack the password of each bank account.')
print('Each and every password is a 3-digit code.')
print('You have 100 lives to do so. Each time you get the password wrong, subtracts a life')
print('After you use up all 100 lives, your bank account will be reset.')
print('Good luck') 

money = 0
lives = 100

def game():
    passwords = random.randint(100, 999)

    while lives <= 100:
        print('Take a guess')
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        if guess < passwords:
            print('Password incorrect. Number too low.')
            lives = lives - 1

        if guess > passwords:
            print('Password incorrect. Number too high')
            lives = lives -1

        if guess == passwords:
            break

    if guess == passwords:
        money = money + passwords
        print('Hacking account...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        print('Account hacked.')
        print('...Adding money to account...')
        print('Your Account:')
        print('$$$: ' + str(money))
        print('Lives: ' + str(lives))
        print('...NEXT ACCOUNT...')
        print('')
        print('')
        time.sleep(2)
        game()
game()
```

When it says `lives` was referenced before assignment. I understand that since `lives` wasn't assigned in the block of code that had `while lives <= 100:` But where could I place the assignments to make the assignment before it is referenced. I know where you could place it but... If someone was to guess the password correct, I don't want to money to be reset back to 0 and the lives to be reset back to 100 when going on to the next account. Please help, and thank you!!!

Comment: As the first line after `def game():` add the following: `global live` - you should declare it as global if you want to be able to refer to it! Sidenote: it's a better practice to avoid using globals. Think carefully if you really need to - or if you can pass it to the function instead!

Comment: @alfasin wouldn't it make the live variable available in all scopes?

Comment: @PatrickBassut it already is (by declaring it outside of the function)

Comment: @alfasin Didn't see that. I thought it wasn't declared at all

Comment: @alfasin Thank you so much!!! It worked!

Comment: @AntonioAnselmo though it worked - you should *really* pay attention to the other part of the comment. :)

Comment: @alfasin I'll make sure I don't use it too often :)

Answer (score 0):

Python's functions are [function scoped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Function_scope). So you'd need to place lives inside the function definition but before the `while` loop before referring to it. On the other hand, you could explicitly declare it to refer to the global version of lives as declared there in your program. Or you could define game as having a parameter that is passed and then assigned called "lives".

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your global variables into a container class. Initialize them in the constructor (the `__init__` method below) and instead of calling `game` from inside, make an outer loop that creates a new game each time.

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lives = 100
        self.money = 0

    def run(self):
        password = random.randint(100, 999)
        while self.lives < 100:
           ...
        ...
        time.sleep(2)
        # game()

while True:
    g = Game()
    g.run()
```

Comment: I thought it would work at first and I hoped it did, but the output of this solution (or what I thought would be the solution) was `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Antonio/Desktop/moneygame.py", line 68, in <module>
    g.run()
  File "C:/Users/Antonio/Desktop/moneygame.py", line 47, in run
    if guess == passwords:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'guess' referenced before assignment`

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your guess variable. Make sure there is no typos in your variable and do notice the difference between `self.<variable>` (property of your Game object) and simple `<variable>` (variable in your local scope).